# How can non-humanoids benefit from enlarge person?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, races

I am playing a tiefling who is a native outsider. During play it has come to my attention that enlarge person will not work for me because I am not a humanoid. This seems like a silly restriction since there are many non-humanoid races presented for us to choose from. So how can I benefit from enlarge person or a similar spell (similar as in duration and spell level). Yes in theory I could use the rules for creating a new spell but I am hoping that there is already something that exists.

It seems that I was not clear enough. I am looking for a solution that will work for all non-humanoids. Not just tieflings.

Comment: @HeyICanChan Good question, I would prefer core material, but if there is something balanced in 3rd party I might be able to swing it by the dm

Answer (score 7):

### Take the 'pass for human' racial trait.

Tieflings and aasimar both possess alternate racial trait options that allow them to count as humanoids in addition to outsiders for basically everything, specifically mentioning *enlarge person*.  The trait replaces the free language and, for tieflings, prohibits some other alternate racial traits being chosen, but the real cost is that counting as a human is generally a bad thing, not a good one.

Comment: This is useful, but only helps those two races.

Comment: @Fering did you need options for any other races?

Comment: I have a Shabti in another game which could also benefit from enlarge person. So just having a general way of doing it would be helpful than a more selective trait.

Comment: @Fering - add that to the question.

Answer (score 1):

If the creature already can't benefit from an effect like the spell [*enlarge person*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/e/enlarge-person), the creature should still be able to benefit from an effect like the spell [*righteous might*](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/spells/righteousMight.html#righteous-might), although that's an extravagance if the creature *only* wants to increase its size category!

### …So how about third-party material?

At only 50 gp, a *[psionic tattoo](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/psionics-unleashed/equipment/psionic-items/psionic-tattoos/) of [expansion](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/psionics-unleashed/psionic-powers/e/expansion/)* (1st-level power at manifester level 1) has, essentially, the same effect as the [*enlarge person*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/e/enlarge-person) spell but the power has the entry *Range: Personal* unlike the spell's *Target: One humanoid creature*. Also, [unlike a potion](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/item-creation-feats/brew-potion-item-creation-final/), for example, a psionic tattoo *can* be created for a power that has an entry of *Range: Personal*.

(Dreamscarred Press's third-party *Pathfinder* psionics material draws much of its inspiration from *Pathfinder*'s antecedent *D&D 3.5e*, where the same [option](http://dndsrd.net/psionicItemsCCDT.html#psionic-tattoo-activation) [exists](http://dndsrd.net/psionicPowersDtoF.html#expansion).)

---

***Note:*** My favorite option—and, perhaps, the only *option—for* instantaneous *size increase comes from drawing the 5 of diamonds from the* [harrow deck of many things](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/artifacts/minor-artifacts/deck-of-many-things-harrow) *minor artifact. Good luck!*

Comment: I want to point out that Dreamscarred Press material is top quality and really well balanced. *Ultimate Psionics* is the one 3rd party book that I permit on my tables without fear.

Answer (score 0):

The [*frightful aspect*](https://aonprd.com/SpellDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Frightful%20Aspect) spell (*Ultimate Combat*, p. 230) could work:

> You become a larger, awful version of yourself. You grow to size Large, and take on features that horrify your enemies. You gain the following abilities: a +6 size bonus to Strength, a +4 size bonus to Constitution, a +6 natural armor bonus, DR 10/magic, and spell resistance equal to 10 + half your caster level. You also emit an aura that emanates 30 feet from you. Enemy creatures within the aura are shaken. Each time a creature shaken by this aura hits you with a melee attack, that creature becomes frightened for 1d4 rounds, though at the end of that duration it is no longer affected by this aura. The aura’s effect is a fear and mind-affecting effect.

But it has a range of **personal** and it's **8th-level**.